# Update the JPlayer MP3 file each time a function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

```
function showAudioFull(id)
{
    var url = URL_DIRSCREENAUDIOSHOT+AUDIOSHOT_PREFIX+id+'.mp3';
    var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_audioFile",
            {
                m4a: url              
            }, {
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1"
            });
}
```

I am appending the MP3 link to JPlayer each time I call this function in my JS file.

There will be a set of images with "id". With an onClick() function this showAudioFull() is invoked.

But problem is JPlayer is not updating the mp3 file that is being played. It keeps playing the same audio which I click at the first time.

FYI : Using JPlayer Circle player

Comment: what is the reason you are creating a new player every time?

Comment: @user1852503 I am just trying to update the file link. I dont have an idea about JPlayer so far. 

My requirement is as follows : If I click first image with id "1" then jplayer should play 1.mp3. In case if i click the 2nd image with id "2", the Jplayer should play 2.mp3 in the same player instead of 1.mp3

Comment: http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-fundamentals. search for "setMedia".

Comment: @user1852503 setMedia is fine. but problem is I initialize the player in document.ready. But the MP3 is provided in another function in the same JS file. Any suggestion on how to go through this?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_audioFile", {
    m4a: url
}, {
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1"
});

function showAudioFull(id) {
    var url = URL_DIRSCREENAUDIOSHOT + AUDIOSHOT_PREFIX + id + '.mp3';
    myCirclePlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: url
    });
};
```

> This method (setMedia) is used to define the media to play. The media parameter
>   is an object that has properties defining the different encoding
>   formats and a poster image. *Source: [jPlayer dev guide](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-setMedia)*

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: myCirclePlayer is not defined

Comment: It shows the same Reference error for m4a: url also.

Comment: You've to make `myCirclePlayer` global accessible on your page for interacting with it in functions.

Comment: I tried setting it Global variable. But now I got this error. "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'myCirclePlayer' of object [object Object] is not a function "

Does circle player allow setMedia property? could you help me with this @alexP